# SSLH multiplexing - custom protocol (DNS)

Tags: linux, dns

I am using SSLH multiplexer for SSH and OpenVPN, but i need to use it for DNS server also (I am multiplexing everything on port 53 - I can't use another port). I've read that SSLH can do this (using regular expressions), but I can't find any way how to realize this. Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be straightforward. Presuming standard ports for ssh and openvpn daemons, then then body of your sslh.conf file would be like

```
listen:
(
    { host: "your.host.name.or.ip.address"; port: "53"; }
);
protocols:
(
    { name: "ssh"; service: "ssh"; host: "localhost"; port: "22"; },
    { name: "openvpn"; host: "localhost"; port: "1194"; },
    { name: "anyprot"; host: "localhost"; port: "53"; }
);
```

But you will need your dns server **NOT** to bind on your external interface for listening - only on the loopback device.